# Weights Optimization in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, linear-programming

I have to do optimization in supervised learning to get my weights.

I have to learn the values `(w1,w2,w3,w4)` such that whenever my vector `A = [a1 a2 a3 a4]` is 1 the sum `w1*a1 + w2*a2 + w3*a3 + w4*a4` becomes greater than 0.5 and when its -1 ( labels ) then it becomes less than 0.5.

Can somebody tell me how I can approach this problem in Matlab ? One way that I know is to do it using evolutionary algorithms, taking a random value vector and then changing to pick the best n values.

Is there any other way that this can be approached ?

Comment: what have you done up to now? SO is not meant for solving problems on demand, but for sharing knowledge. SO members do like to assess the effort amount the OP put into solving the proposed problem.

Comment: @fpe One of the solutions that I have come up with is to just pass these vectors in SVM and I guess it would be doing the same thing with a linear kernel. I have also looked at `linprog` but am unable to understand how to use it in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html).
Let `A` be a matrix of size `n` by 4 consisting of all `n` training 4-vecotrs you have. You should also have a vector `y` with `n` elements (each either plus or minus 1), representing the label of each training 4-vecvtor.

Using `A` and `y` we can write a linear program (look at the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) for the names of the parameters I'm using). Now, you do not have an objective function, so you can simply set `f` to be `f = zeros(4,1);`.
The only thing you have is an inequality constraint `(< a_i , w > - .5) * y_i >= 0` (where `<.,.>` is a dot-product between 4-vector `a_i` and weight vector `w`).
If my calculations are correct, this constraint can be written as

```
cmat = bsxfun( @times, A, y );
```

Overall you get

```
w = linprog( zeros(4,1), -cmat, .5*y );
```